# How do I allow users to modify other user details without superuser status? (Django/Python)

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-admin

I'm setting up my app just now, and I have created an admin panel, which amongst other features, allows for creation/editing/deletion of users. I implemented all this and it worked fine, but then I realised that the entire time I had been logged in as a superuser -_-

Of course, as soon as I logged in as a normal registered user, it didn't work (as it shouldn't I guess).

My question is: how do I allow certain users to change other user's details without being a superuser?

P.S. I've looked into groups and permissions, but none of it seems to cover editing of user information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just give the following permissions to a user and he'll be able to change the user details of other users:

```
auth | User | can add user
auth | User | can modify user
auth | User | can delete user
```

Don't forget to also make the user with the above permissions a stuff member in order to allow him to login to the admin interface.

**Update**
Here's a small snippet on how to set permissions programatically to allow a User to modify other users:

```
import django.contrib.auth
# let's get the User permissions         
user_perms=django.contrib.auth.models.Permission.objects.filter(content_type__name='user')
# let's find a user
u = django.contrib.auth.models.User.objects.get(username='xxx')
# add the permissions to the user
for up in user_perms:
    u.user_permissions.add(up)
# and make the user a staff member
u.is_staff = True
u.save()
```

Comment: Sorry, I am possibly being incredibly dense, but I can't see how to implement what you described. Could you possibly show me a small example of how to implement something like that?

I looked here (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) and can see that a User type has permissions. I know how to add permissions fine, but the permissions you mentioned, would it be a case of something like `emp.user_permissions.add(User.can_add_user)`?

Comment: You can simply add these permissions to a user through the admin interface - I'll also update my answer with a small script that will help you adding them to a User through code.

Comment: Note that if you can add and modify a user, you can create a superuser, then make any changes you like.